# Can this generic navigation command be improved?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I've been looking for a way to create a navigation where I use a command binding with an in-view-specified command parameter to execute a "generic" navigation command in my ViewModel.

This is the original Navigation implementation in a custom Navigation Service found in the [enterprise application example](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers).

```cs
        public Task NavigateToAsync<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            return InternalNavigateToAsync(typeof(TViewModel), null);
        }
```

You drive this by calling:

```cs
NavigateToAsync<SomeViewModel>();
```

The best I have been able to come up with is to substitute the implementation above with:

```cs
        public Task NavigateToAsync(Type viewModel)
        {
            return InternalNavigateToAsync(viewModel, null);
        }
```

Where the ViewModel type is passed as a command parameter from the commanding view.

What I'm looking for is to find out if it is possible to combine these two instead of having to rely on separate implementations.

I'd like to retain this,

```cs
NavigateToAsync<TViewModel>();
```

but some how be able to call and infer the  from the view's command parameter.

Does this sound reasonable at all?

Sorry for not being able to express my issue more coherently as I'm quite at the brink of my current capabilities.

I know I could've maybe compressed my question into a few sentences, if I knew exactly what it is that I'm looking to describe.

I'd appreciate any pointers towards possible sources on this as my progress is turning stale.

Cheers.

EDITS:
Thanks to [G.hakim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7462031/g-hakim) for asking.

By using these:

```xml
            <Button
                Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type vm:SomeViewModel}" />
```

```cs
public ICommand NavigationCommand
 => new Command<Type>(async (Type viewModelType)
 => await Navigate(viewModelType));
```

I'm able to use a single command for navigation to many different views and
as such I think I'm able to prevent having to write multiple navigation commands.

Comment: I am curious here what exactly is the problem with the existing `NavigateToAsync` method that you are trying to come up with this change?

Comment: @G.hakim I tried providing you with some further details.

Comment: So what you basically want is a generic way of calling ViewModel's for navigation am I correct?

Comment: I think so - yes. And I've achieved that by passing the ViewModel type as a method parameter, but I feel that I should be able to infer the type into the <> diamond operator somehow.

Comment: Instead of:
`await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(viewModelType);`
I'm trying to achieve this:
`await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<viewModelType>();`

P.S. Sorry for spastic comment edits.

Comment: Did you try out the answer below for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is something like this :

```
 public Task NavigateToAsync<T>() 
    {
        return InternalNavigateToAsync(typeof(T), null);
    }
```

Now this generic will accept whatever you push in the `T`

For more information on how generics work you can check [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) documents for the same.

Also, you can specify exactly which type the generic should be so you do not face runtime errors of any kind, by adding a where clause to it.

```
 public Task NavigateToAsync<T>() where T : YourViewModelType
    {
        return InternalNavigateToAsync(typeof(T), null);
    }
```